# Is there file size limit for the imported .dat file?

Tags: dm-script

I meet a problem for the large stacked images of several GB. Actually, I can directly open a stacked image (dm4 format) of 9GB (1000x1000x1000), but if I want to rotate it using volumn operation such as "rotate about x", the GMS or DM exits automatically. I write a simple script code to complete the operation with the slice3 function and display the result correctly, but I cannot save it! If I try to save the resulted stacked image, software says "sorry" and forces me to close it.
OK, I think this file is too large to the software's capability. So I save the original data file to .dat formate and write a fortran code to rotate it, then save the result as a .dat file. When I use the import function of GMS or DM, it only imports first several hundred frames, not all frames.
How to deal with it?

Comment: A 1000x1000x1000 real image (4-byte) will only be <4GB. What data format are you using in your image?

Answer (score 0):

There certainly are size restrictions in both total size and maximum length along one dimension, but I don't think 1000 x 1000 x 1000 should be a limiting factor.

I just ran the following two scripts in order and saved the data on my GMS 3.4.3 without problem.

```c
image big := RealImage("Big First",4,1000,1000,1000)
big = icol*sin(irow/iheight*100*pi())*10000+iplane
big.showimage()
```

```c
image bigIn := A
image bigOut := bigIn.Slice3(0,0,0, 1,1000,1,0,1000,1,2,1000,1)
bigOut.ShowImage()
```

[image]

---

Can you edit you question to include the script code you're failing to run and other useful information?

Comment: I change your code to rotate the whole image along x axis, I find the same error message when try to save it.

Comment: image bigOut := bigIn.Slice3(0,0,0, 0,1000,1,2,1000,1,1,1000,1)

Comment: The image can be displayed correctly, but when I save it, a Error message jumps. "DM has encountered an unrecoverable error"

Comment: @YuanYao I see no such thing, just tested. I'm using GMS 3.4.3.3213 for this test. However, a 1000x1000x1000x4bytes image is just shy of 4GB in size, not 9GB. So I retested using 8-byte real as well - still no issue. Are you using the File/Save as... for saving or something different?

Comment: I update the GMS to 3.4.3xxx and the problem does not appear. Maybe there are something wrong for my old version. Thank you very much!